# Validation button in easyadmin Symfony5

Tags: symfony

is it possible to add a validation task when you click on save changes on easyadmin's (when you're about to add something)it appears automatically when Im about to delete the question "do you really wanna delete? press yes or no" I want that while adding something , thank you so much :)

Comment: I know that ask_confirm: true  can do probably but I did put it inside  - { entity: Article , label: "Add Article" , icon: "plus", params: {action: 'new'}, ask_confirm: true } doesnt work

Comment: What version of EasyAdmin are you using?

Comment: no clue honestly , but since 2019 using it

Comment: Well, look at the output of `composer show`